# CSS Media Queries aren't resetting

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm using 3 Media Queries on my Site:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) 
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)       
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px)
```

When you drag the browser window in everything re-sizes fine, but when you drag it back out again the navigation doesn't go back to where it should - everything else goes back fine.

The Website is [here](http://creatrixtest.com/manfood/).

Is there something I am missing to make the Navgation go back to its starting position?

Comment: Works perfectly in FF 19.0.2 under Win 7.

Comment: Thanks, i've just realised it's only an issue in Google Chrome as it works fine in IE as well.

Comment: For the record, I've noticed this happening from time to time (not always) in Chrome (v25 win 7) as well.

Comment: @creatrix Nice design, btw. ManFood :)

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? It works fine for me in Chrome 25.0.1364.172 m on Windows 7.

Comment: I get a `Not Found` on the link you specified

Comment: Works fine in my Chrome. Disable plugins time?

Comment: I can't see your website but I have the same problem on a different site - just specific to Chrome for me...

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a min and max selectors like

```
@media only screen and (min-height : 0px) and (max-height: 600px) {
/* bla bla bla */ 
}
```